# Determining convergence of Fourier Series for even and odd extensions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, piecewise-continuity

I have a piece-wise function as follows: $$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \quad 0 < x \leq {\pi\over2} \\
            0 & \quad {\pi\over 2}< x < \pi
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
I am supposed to sketch the even and odd extension of $f$ and compute the Fourier Series for each.

I got $$f_{even}(x)={a_0\over 2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(nx)$$ $$a_n={2\over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)dx$$ $$n=1,2,...$$ $$a_0={1\over 2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx$$

and 
$$f_{odd}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin(nx)$$ $$b_n={2\over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(nx)dx$$ $$n=1,2,...$$

I want to determine whether or not the Fourier Series converges uniformly to $f$ for each. I think it does, since we know that if $f$ is periodic, continuous, and has a piece-wise continuous derivative then the Fourier series associated to $f$ converges uniformly. I don't know if there is a way to see this without doing a calculation or if it's necessary to work it out.

Comment: Do you think that $f$ is continuous ?